# Allure Reports - Fail in middle steps scenario doesn't stop test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, junit, allure

I'm using Java 11, Selenium, Junit, Allure Reports in my testing project.
I'd like in my allure report to failed steps doesn't stop test. Is it possible after fail "When" step test doesn't stopped and continues next step "Then"?

[Allure Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLhQl.png)

I tried several methods but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Cucumber works. After a step fails, the rest of the steps are reported as skipped. Please note that skipped steps have not been executed and are only shown in the report for documentation purposes.